How to add function to prototype of an interface that is actually a class？
It is easy to add add function to prototype of a value, for example:
Array.prototype.removeAt = function (index) {
  if (index >= 0 && index < this.length) {
    this.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return this;
};

declare global {
  export interface Array<T> {
    removeAt(index: number): Array<T>;
  }
}

But it does not work any more when I try to add function to prototype of an interface (which  is actually a class, so it has prototype). For example:
import { Router, RouteRecord } from 'vue-router';

Router.prototype.getRouteByName = function (this: Router, name: string): RouteRecord | undefined {
  return this.getRoutes().find(m => m.name === name);
};

declare global {
  export interface Router {
    getRouteByName(name: string): RouteRecord | undefined;
  }
}

I get an error when I compile it: 'Router' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
However, the type 'Router' is exported as an interface while it is actually a class in the JavaScript code behind, so I think there must be a way to bypass this restriction and mutate its prototype.
Here is how Router is exported:
export interface Router {
 // so many members, please see the detains on 
 // https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/src/router.ts#L189
}

What should I do to achieve it?

Please show us where and how vue-router exports that class (and/or interface) that you want to modify

Does the code actually work at runtime?

Oh, I was looking at https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router not https://github.com/vuejs/router/tree/main/packages/router

"while it is actually a class in the JavaScript code behind" - no, it isn't

@Bergi yeah, you are right, I just know it after viewing the latest source code.

Router is an interface here, not a class function, and more over a router instance is just a plain object so you cannot extend any EXPOSED prototype here, your code doesn't even run:
  const router = { // returned from createRouter
    currentRoute,
    listening: true,
    addRoute,
    removeRoute,
    clearRoutes: matcher.clearRoutes,
    hasRoute,
    getRoutes,
    resolve,
    options,
    push,
    replace,
    go,
...

Just override createRouter() any way you like, here I use a class:
import { createRouter as createVueRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';

interface MyRouter extends ReturnType<typeof createVueRouter> { };
class MyRouter implements MyRouter {
    getRouteByName(name: string) {
        return this.getRoutes().find(m => m.name === name);
    };
}

export function createRouter(...params: Parameters<typeof createVueRouter>): MyRouter {
    const router = createVueRouter(...params);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(router, MyRouter.prototype);
    return router as MyRouter;
}

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(), routes: [{
        path: '/',
        name: 'test',
        component: () => import('./test.vue')
    }]
});

const route = router.getRouteByName('test');

So import this function and use it instead of the original createRouter

Why not just router.getRouteByName = … instead of Object.setPrototypeOf(router, MyRouter.prototype);? Or even return { ...router, getRouteByName(name: string) { … } };

@Bergi just fond of classes ‍♂️, but your method also works

You extend this not through declare global but
import type { Router, RouteRecord } from 'vue-router';
// I'm not sure which one you need from these two.
import 'vue-router';

declare module 'vue-router' {
   // not sure if you need the export keyword here
   export interface Router {
       getRouteByName(name: string): RouteRecord | 
           undefined;
   }
}

You either need to import this file wherever you wanna use getRouteByName or you have to add it as an ambient type declaration file to you tsconfig. (typeRoots, files,...not sure)
Btw, router is actually a plain JS object so prototyping it might not be so productive just create your own router plugin or router factory function like createRouter that wraps createRouter.

The answer addresses only type part of the question

OP obviously knows how to extend the prototype because it was done well in the question (but as I said Router is not a class but a POJO returned by a factory). Don't be aegumentative when it's useless.
